# How to use bcrypt module to save encrypted password in MongoDB using NestJS

Tags: typescript, authentication, postman, nestjs, bcrypt

How can I save an encrypted password to MongoDB?

P.S. I'm a beginner developer and still learning how to use NestJS

Comment: bcrypt is not an encryption algorithm, it is a hashing algorithm. You cannot use bcrypt to encrypt a password.

Comment: okay my first doubt is cleared.Now how can i save encrypted password into mongo db database,Which module is build for this and how do i use that module in my nest app

Comment: For encryption, use an encryption algorithm. But you should never store encrypted passwords.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using TypeOrm there is a decorator name's **@BeforeInsert()**

```
@Entity("YourTable", { schema: "yourdb" })
export class YourTable {
   ...
   @BeforeInsert()
   async hashPassword() {
      this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, Number(process.env.HASH_SALT));
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: And what if I am using mongoose? Any idea? THanks :)