# How to fix "can not fin'd bcrypt" in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, bcrypt

As found in this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61269160/how-to-use-bcrypt-module-to-save-encrypted-password-in-mongodb-using-nestjs), the following thing could be a way how to encrypt a password into a hash:

```
  @BeforeInsert() async hashPassword() {
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, Number(process.env.HASH_SALT));
  }
```

However, although I have installed "bcrypt" and "types/bcrypt", it can't get found by NodeJS:

> src/entities/user.entity.ts:50:27 - error TS2552: Cannot find name
> 'bcrypt'. Did you mean 'crypto'?

In my package.json the following lines show that bcrypt was successfully installed:

```
"@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
"bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you show your code and how you are importing and using the package?

Comment: it was ìmport bcrypt from 'bcrypt' which did not work out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import the bcrypt on the files where you use it like this:

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
```